# missing file when serving nx project

Tags: angular, nx-monorepo, narwhal

I recently had to migrate a projet in a Nx monorepo.
after creating a projet and manually swapping the src folder, I made a bunch of changes to fix the compilations errors. Now that it compiles successfully i get a white page and when i check the console i have multiples 404 on some modules:

```
Request URL:
http://localhost:4200/@fs/C:/Users/my.name/Desktop/codes/Hubbix%20Comptabilite/node_modules/vite/dist/client/env.mjs
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
404 Not Found
Remote Address:
[::1]:4200
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

this was one of them.
the complete list is:
env.mjs

- @angular_platform-browser.js
- @angular_core.js
- @angular_router.js
- ng-zorro-antd_i18n.js
- @angular_common_locales_fr.js
- @angular_common_http.js
- @angular_platform_browser_animations.js
- ng-zorro-antd_notification.js
- and an other inhouse package.

Its basically saying that those files are not there, but i checked and they are in the right folder. i tried deleting the angular folder an re-serving the project but it didnt work.
Is anyone familliar with this issue?